# Magento category path changing

Tags: php, magento, categories

Can someone help me with the following problem:

I would like to change the URL of the categories.

It is now as follows http://tuinbeursnederland.nl.testbyte.nl/blokhutten-tuinhuizen/blokhutten/op-maat/

And I want it like this way: http://tuinbeursnederland.nl.testbyte.nl/blokhutten/op-maat/

But the category /blokhutten-tuinhuizen/ must remain.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with url rewrite.

Go to url rewrite and add custom url rewrite, give unique id path.

And in request path give `http://tuinbeursnederland.nl.testbyte.nl/blokhutten-tuinhuizen/blokhutten/op-maat/` this url and in target path give this url `http://tuinbeursnederland.nl.testbyte.nl/blokhutten/op-maat/` magento internally consider target path for its use.

For more Info on url rewrite you can see here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/

Answer (score 0):

```
class CP_Core_Model_Catalogurl extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
{
    /**
     * Retrieve Category URL
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
   public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
        $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
        $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

        if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
            $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
            $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
        }

        if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
        }
        else {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
        if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        }
        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());
        $parentPath = '';

        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $requestPath;
        }

        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
        );
    }


}
```

Please override module customize this function like i do above.

Comment: Hello Dharmesh Hariyani,

Which file should I exactly adjust?